# What are typical max speeds for pro downhill races?

Tags: mountain-bike, speed, downhill

Looking videos like Red Bull Rampage or Mega Avalanche make me wonder about the speeds attained by those pro bikers. How fast they go in straight line sections?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The differences are quite significant from race to race - each track is different. Also events such as Rampage are not too much about speed. The top speed may vary between 55-65km/h on tracks such as Mount Sainte Anne up to around 80km/h in Pietermaritzburg which is known for high speeds achieved. Of course all assuming good weather.

Also these speeds are kept only for a few seconds (in the best case), the average speeds come around 30km/h mark course and weather dependent.

Answer (score 2):

These days we have Strava for this. Check for example (Strava account required to see details of individual rides):

- [Mont ventoux descent.](http://www.strava.com/segments/mont-ventoux-descent-to-malauc%C3%A8ne-1410555)
- [Galibier descent](http://www.strava.com/segments/1294034)
- [Alpe d'Huez descent](http://www.strava.com/segments/4391613)

You'll find some segments there, and quite often you also get tracks from pro cyclists. From looking at just a few KOMS I see that top speeds at about 110-120 km/h are not uncommon. You can find interviews with pro riders where they boast about speeds up to about 140-150 km/h. Above that seems highly unlikely because you're approaching [terminal velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) and at those speed pedalling isn't going to help you.

*Note:* Updated to show actual segments (no account needed), but to see maximum speeds, you do need an account.

Comment: I avoid sites and apps that require creating an account before using it (Strava, MapMyRide). Information wants to be free.

Comment: Are those speeds for road bikes or downhill?

Comment: I would guess road bikes.  Here's one for the downhill track at [Fort William](http://www.strava.com/segments/940836)

Comment: Please edit this answer so it makes sense to people who don't want to give their email address to some website just to find out how fast some bunch of guys ride their bikes.

Comment: With specially designed aerodynamic bikes, suits and helmets, you can achieve much more than that (222km/h is the current record, I believe), but I wouldn't call that "riding" anymore. It's basically "free falling with your wheels gently touching an almost vertical wall of ice".

Comment: @DavidRicherby I guess you'll have to take my word for the 110-120 km/h figure, you need to be logged in to view them it seems.

Comment: @jillesdewit I'd like to see links to those pro interviews you speak of where they state they're going at 140-150kph... I have my doubts. Top road biker pro speeds are around 120kph and that's during races (on closed roads) and only on very particular descents that lend themselves to fast descending. Alp d'Huez is certainly not one of those descents with all its twists and turns.

Comment: @chrisjleu here (in dutch) we have Belgian Philippe Gilbert claiming he has done 140 km/h (after he was clocked going 119) http://www.wielerflits.nl/nieuws/12188/snelheidsduivel-gilbert-rijdt-119-km-per-uur-met-fiets-.html In the econd paragraph he says (roughly): "fast? Not so much, if you really try you can easily reach 140 kph here, I've gone much faster before but I don't know how much. The movie below shows dutch rider Theo Bos doing 140. Both drafting behind a car though. I've seen tv interviews where they claim 150 but I can't find any on-line references.